# Event receiver in console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a console application in which I have defined `ItemAdded` event receiver method. I wanted to know how to execute the `ItemAdded` method, do I need to call this method inside the `Main` function? If yes, then how?

Here is my code

```
class Program : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program pgm = new Program();
    }

    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            SPSite site = new SPSite("http://cdcgtdevvm258/sites/amit/dummy");
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
            SPList list = web.Lists[""];
            SPListItem listitem = properties.List.AddItem();
            listitem["Title"] = "Example";
            listitem.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or something is wrong with the code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event-handlers are called when an event happens. Usually you define an event-handler, assign it to an event and when this event happens your event-handler is called. Example for a button-click:

```
void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
//handle the click-event, update UI, etc.
}
```

You'll need to register this event with the object:

```
button1.Click += button1_click;
```

And every time you'll click the button, your event is called.
There is much stuff on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t.aspx). Please be more specific about your question and tell us what you want to do.

Comment: Somehow this code is not working even on adding an item. So is there a problem with code then?

Comment: I must say I don't really know what you are up to.

Answer (score 0):

If your compile output is console EXE, then it will never work. You need to create the class library (dll) in order to register and attach it as list item event receiver.

In case you just want to test the code written inside ItemAdded then extract function from it. Create two separate project (Console + Class library). Use the class library project as reference in console application and call that method. Call the same method in ItemAdded event. You can register the class library (dll) project as event receiver.

Refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms437502%28v=office.14%29.aspx